# Error using Lambda as key in sorted function

Tags: python

i've been using lambda as key in sorted function and it keeps giving me invalid syntax error anyone knows why?

```
x=[4,32,41,34324,234,2,51,23,-13,1,-1,-3,-543,-214]
sorted(word_counts.items(),key=lambda(word,count):count,reverse=True)
```

Comment: Please show your entire code, we do not know where the variable `word_counts` comes from

Comment: You define `x`, yet never use it anywhere else in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the brackets should fix the problem:

```
x=[4,32,41,34324,234,2,51,23,-13,1,-1,-3,-543,-214]
sorted(word_counts.items(),key=lambda word,count:count,reverse=True)
```